# Weird strong password auto filling behavior in a particular view structure

Tags: ios, swiftui

I found that when **one `TextField` and two `SecureField`s** are in a View, iOS automatically fills both SecureFields with their suggested strong password as soon as it gets focused. It doesn't reproduce when either not having `TextField` or having only one `SecureField`. What weird behavior!

Does anyone know why it happens and how I can avoid auto-filling? I found it doesn't happen if I set keyboard type such as `numberPad` to the SecureField, but I want to them to be password field, it is not an option.

FYI: I'm using the Firebase Dynamic Links with a custom domain and Associated Domains are configured in the app, which enables the password auto-fill.

```swift
struct ExperimentView: View {
    @State private var text1: String = ""
    @State private var text2: String = ""
    @State private var text3: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $text1)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)

            SecureField("", text: $text2)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)

            SecureField("", text: $text3)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Behavior you're experiencing is likely due to the **iOS password auto-fill feature**, which **automatically suggests** strong passwords for **secure fields**.

To **avoid the auto-filling of passwords** in your `SecureFields`, you can try the following:

---

You can use the disableAutocorrection(_: Bool) modifier along with a UITextInputTraits extension to prevent auto-fill. Example:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

extension UITextInputTraits {
    var isPasswordBased: Bool {
        return false
    }
}

struct ExperimentView: View {
    @State private var text1: String = ""
    @State private var text2: String = ""
    @State private var text3: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $text1)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)

            SecureField("", text: $text2)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .introspectTextField { textField in
                    textField.disableAutocorrection(textField.isFirstResponder && text2.isEmpty)
                }

            SecureField("", text: $text3)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .introspectTextField { textField in
                    textField.disableAutocorrection(textField.isFirstResponder && text3.isEmpty)
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

---

As you mentioned, setting the keyboard type to something other than the default password field may also prevent the auto-fill behavior. However, since you want the fields to function as password fields, this may not be a suitable option for you.

---

Let me know if it helps!! If so, **leave your opinions** by voting! ^^

Comment: Setting `none` does not seem to work as expected. When I focus on the first SecureField, it still auto-fills the strong password to both SecureFields.

Comment: How about using `disableAutocorrection(_: Bool)` modifier along with a `UITextInputTraits`. Check my edited code..

Comment: Well, AFAIK to use `introspectTextField` you need 3rd party library but you don't mention it.